# ASP.NET Core running two TestServer for Integration Testing

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, integration-testing

I am trying to run some integration tests for a token management API.  The API also requires the token issuer API to be running.

In summary, my integration test needs to run both IdentityServer4 Web/API and the Management API simultaneously.  When I create two instances of `TestServer`, it seems like they both end up with the same `BaseAddress` (`http://localhost`).

```
private readonly TestServer _identityTestServer;
private readonly TestServer _mgmtTestServer;
private readonly AppMgmtConfig _config;
private readonly AdminClient _adminClient;
private const string _certificatePassword = "test";

public AdminClientTests() : base(nameof(AdminClientTests))
{
    var connectionString = GetConnectionString();
    var dbSettings = new DbSettings(connectionString);

    Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("IdentityServer4ConnString",
        dbSettings.IdentityServerConnectionString);
    Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("CertificatePassword", _certificatePassword);

    _identityTestServer = new TestServer(new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseStartup<USBIdentityServer.Startup>()
        .UseEnvironment("IntegrationTest"));
    USBIdentityServer.Program.InitializeDatabase(_identityTestServer.Host);

    _mgmtTestServer = new TestServer(new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseStartup<IdentityServer4.Management.Startup>()
        .UseEnvironment("IntegrationTest"));

    _config = GetConfig();
    _adminClient = new AdminClient(_config);
}
```

**NOTE:**
Things I have already tried:

- Add `.UseUrls("http://localhost:5001")` to see if TestServer will run on that port.
- Add `serverName.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:5001");` to see if TestServer will run on that port.

Neither of these seems to impact it.

Comment: Have you found any info on this I am actually stuck with a very similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47812182/aspnetcore-testhost-ignoring-usemvc-in-an-nunit-integration-test-in-rider

Comment: Unfortunately I have not

Comment: How do you *interact* with those test servers? As in my integration test with just one server, I'm exercising my API from an `HttpClient` obtained from `myTestServer.CreateClient()`. So it looks like there's a *connection* between Test Server and (Test) Client

Comment: I'm having the same issue

Comment: I had the same issue,  and your suggestions .UseUrls("http://localhost:5001")   and Add serverName.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:5001")worked for me,  however I am using .NET Core 3.0  so maybe an issue was fixed.

Answer (score 9):

I know this is an old question, but I was having the same problem. I think the trick is to inject the HttpClient you got from "server 1" into "server 2".

[From ASP.NET issues:](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/1254)

> Test server does not open any real sockets, so running on different urls is a fictitious concept anyways. You can set BaseAddress to anything you want.
>
> I assume your actual challenge is communicating with those test servers? Again, they don't open any real sockets, the only way to communicate with them is through their CreateClient API which creates an in-memory channel.

Example (.NET Core):

```
//Start and configure server 1.
IWebHostBuilder server1 = new WebHostBuilder()
 .UseStartup < Project1.Startup > ()
 .UseKestrel(options => options.Listen(IPAddress.Any, 80))
 .UseConfiguration(new ConfigurationBuilder()
  .AddJsonFile("appsettings_server1.json")
  .Build()
 );

TestServer testServer1 = new TestServer(server1);

//Get HttpClient that's able to connect to server 1.
HttpClient client1 = server1.CreateClient();

IWebHostBuilder _server2 = new WebHostBuilder()
 .UseStartup < Project2.Startup > ()
 .ConfigureTestServices(
  services => {
   //Inject HttpClient that's able to connect to server 1.
   services.AddSingleton(typeof(HttpClient), client1);
  })
 .UseKestrel(options => options.Listen(IPAddress.Any, 81))
 .UseConfiguration(new ConfigurationBuilder()
  .AddJsonFile("appsettings_server2.json")
  .Build()
 );

TestServer testServer2 = new TestServer(server2);
```

Comment: Do you have Idea how to deal with 3 TestServers, where you need to inject 2 HttpClients to use them for different microservices requests?

Comment: Since we don't have 3 testservers I haven't spend much time on doing this and I am sorry to say, but I have no idea on how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on .NET Core 3.1 and I extended reply provided by @Sander.

Here you have working solution for 2 microservices: Adapter and Objects.
I wanted to call Objects API from Adapter service.

If you need more than 1 client you should wrap it in specific client wrapper (ObjectsApiClient in my case), set proper BaseAddress and it should work.

```
// Adapter microservice - Objects microservice client wrapper

public class ObjectsApiClient
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

    public ObjectsApiClient(
        HttpClient httpClient,
        IAuthorizationService authorizationService, // additional services you need in your client wrapper
        IHttpHeaderAppService httpHeaderAppService)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClient;
        ...
    }
}

// Adapter microservice - Startup class 

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    services.AddHttpClient<ObjectsApiClient>(client =>
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost/api/v1/objects/");
        })
}

// Adapter microservice integration test class

private IHost _testServer;
private IHost _objectsTestServer;

// Adapter microservice integration test constructor

_objectsTestServer = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureWebHost(webHost =>
        webHost
            .UseStartup(typeof(Objects.Startup))
            .UseConfiguration(configuration)
            .UseTestServer())
    .Start();

var objectsHttpClient = _objectsTestServer.GetTestClient();
objectsHttpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost/api/v1/objects/");

var objectsApiClient = new ObjectsApiClient(
    objectsHttpClient,
    _objectsTestServer.Services.GetService<IAuthorizationService>(),    // inject services you need in your client wrapper
    _objectsTestServer.Services.GetService<IHttpHeaderAppService>());   

_testServer = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureWebHost(webHost =>
        webHost
            .UseStartup(typeof(Startup))
            .UseConfiguration(configuration)
            .ConfigureTestServices(config => config
                .AddSingleton(typeof(ObjectsApiClient), objectsApiClient)) // you can register other typed clients here
            .UseTestServer())
    .Start();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a bad design, but I think is worth mentioning on that question - *launching tested services in separate processes*.

Example with NUnit:

```
[SetUpFixture]
public class GlobalSetUpFixture 
{
    private static Process firstServiceProcess;
    private static Process secondServiceProcess;
    
    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public async Task RunBeforeTests()
    {
        var firstPath = "path/to/first/csproj";
        var secondPath = "path/to/second/csproj";

        var firstCommandArguments = $"run -p {firstPath}\\FirstProject.csproj --launch-profile TestsEnvironment";
        var secondCommandArguments = $"run -p {secondPath}\\SecondProject.csproj --launch-profile TestsEnvironment";

        var firstProcessInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
        {
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            UseShellExecute = true,
            FileName = "dotnet",
            Arguments = firstCommandArguments 
        };
        var secondProcessInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
        {
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            UseShellExecute = true,
            FileName = "dotnet",
            Arguments = secondCommandArguments
        };

        firstServiceProcess = Process.Start(firstProcessInfo);
        secondServiceProcess = Process.Start(secondProcessInfo);
    }

    [OneTimeTearDown]
    public async Task RunAfterTests()
    {
        firstServiceProcess?.Kill();
        secondServiceProcess?.Kill();
    }
}
```

This solution may have some use cases:

- The need to run multiple services at the same time (eg. with interdependencies between them).
- An alternative to dependency injection HttpClient, IHttpClientFactory, and other connections like SignalR (WebSockets).
- Services are running with real sockets and can communicate with each other.
- It could be an easier approach, than adapting current projects to run tests.

Answer (score 1):

All previous solutions work, but they do the correct thing in the wrong way.
Instead of injecting `HttpClient` or some kind of wrapper in the DI, the `HttpClient` should be configured using `IHttpClientFactory`. Assuming you have configured 2 test servers: `testServer1` and `testServer2`, and want to call them from the third test server:

```cs
.ConfigureServices(services =>
{
    services
        .AddHttpClient<TestServer1Client>()
        .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() => testServer1.CreateHandler());

    services
        .AddHttpClient<TestServer2Client>()
        .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() => testServer2.CreateHandler());
})
```