# How to write Unit Tests for a ASP.NET Core gRPC service that depends on another gRPC service?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, grpc-c#

I'm trying to make tests for my ASP.NET Core gRPC services. I currently have 2 services that I'd like to test: `UserService` and `IdentityService`.

For user service everything is fine. Using EF Core's in-memory DB and `Grpc.Core.Testing.TestServerCallContext` class, I'm able to directly instantiate the class and call its methods.

But for `IdentityService`, I have a problem. Because it gets `UserService`'s client as a constructor parameter, I can't successfully make an instance of it. This is its header:

```cs
public class IdentityService 
    (UsersProto.UsersProtoClient usersApiClient, IdentityDbContext dbContext, TimeProvider timeProvider) 
    : IdentityProto.IdentityProtoBase
{
```

I've even tried to make the testing project reference the gRPC proto as a client, and `UsersProto.UsersProtoClient` is now being generated in the test class *too*. The problem is the `IdentityService` accepts `Users.Api.UsersProtoClient`, but the client class that is generated in the test project is, actually the same thing, but because it's generated in a different namespace, `IdentityService` doesn't accept it as a parameter.

Note that I was able to use Moq to mock the client class in tests, my problem is that `IdentityService` won't accept the gRPC client class that is generated in a foreign project. In other words, what I'm looking for is accessing the gRPC auto-generated client class that is generated inside the Identity API project from another project, the tests project in my case. How can I do this?

Comment: Do you have in place or at least heard of "Mocking Frameworks" before? The more famous ones being Moq, NSubstitute, ... something like that?

Comment: Yes @Fildor, do they work for gRPC services too?

Comment: Why wouldn't they? You just need a thing to throw in that pretends to do something ... they do.

Comment: Testing is explained in the docs: [Mock Clients in Tests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/test-client?view=aspnetcore-8.0) and [Test gRPC services in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/test-services?view=aspnetcore-8.0). The examples use Moq to mock clients and services

Comment: In addition to @PanagiotisKanavos comment see this answer to understand how to make one test server call another test server during the integration test: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76210876/2557855

Comment: @Artur Isn't there a way to achieve this in Unit Tests?

Comment: I didn't try it, but it should be easy to mock the `Grpc.Core.CallInvoker` needed to instantiate your `UsersProtoClient`. Just return the required `TResponse` or throw the `Grpc.Core.RpcException` with the desired status code.

Comment: And looking into @PanagiotisKanavos link, there is a simple way to mock the client. Check his link: `Mock Clients in Tests`. You don't need to regenerate the client, you need to [mock](https://github.com/devlooped/moq/wiki/Quickstart) the original client.

Comment: @Artur I can mock the client if I can access it. My problem is I can't access the source-generated client class from another project (Unit Tests project). If I could, everything else would be fine. If you know how to do this or know another workaround for writing Unit Tests for my case, can you please do me a favor and write an answer?

Comment: But why can't you access it? Isn't it public?

Comment: @Artur if you'd like to reproduce this problem you can create an ASP.NET Core gRPC app, then create another gRPC app that calls the first one (using connected services), and a test project that tests the second project. My only problem is how can I pass the first gRPC client class (mocked) to the second service.